# Laravel assets, routes and pages

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I think this is an easy one, but i'm really confused myself.

1. myproject.com/index.php shows my project main page
2. myproject.com shows my project main page too.
3. In 1st case, after routing it works fine (i.e. : myproject.com/index.php/register)
4. In 2nd case, after routing it fails (i.e. : myproject.com/register) with following error : The requested URL /register was not found on this server.

So because of that, i thought that i had to re-route every request for myproject.com to myproject.com/index.php

**app/config/app.php :**

```
'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/public',
```

**etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myproject/public/"
     ServerName myproject.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing's been configured in hosts file.

**Goal**: how can i re-route all requests from **myproject.com** to **myproject.com/index.php** with hiding index.php part of from users ?

Visitors should see that : myproject.com
but i want them to actually reach : myproject.com/index.php

**Workaround:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myproject/public/index.php"
    ServerName myproject.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Result : I cannot reach the assets, (js, css files) results with 404 because my browser is not allowed to reach **myproject.com/public/**. Root has been set as **myproject.com/public/index.php** in this virtualhost settings.

Comment: Haven't you forgot to add the `AllowOverride all`  in the `<Directory>` directive  in your Vhost Configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the .htaccess file is present in your public directory.

If not check the [Pretty Url](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) Section.

Also make sure that you put `<Directory>` directives in your vhost configuration just to be on the safe side.

Eg:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/myproject/public/">
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from All
 </Directory>
```

Concerning the `'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1/public',` in app.php am pretty much sure the `/public` is kinda extra.

`'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1',` should be working fine.

Comment: Pretty url section is checked. Directory part has solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need rewrite rules for this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#pretty-urls